# Change foreach loop to a for loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach

I'm quite new to PHP. How can I change this foreach loop to only loop twice?

```
<?php 

foreach($results as $row):

?>
```

Comment: You need a counter variable, which you can simply increment and check if it is equals to 2, if yes break the loop.

Comment: Then use for loop for that

Comment: Do please give it some though / Give it a try yourself, nothing will explode if you try, and it's the best way to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, you just need a counter variable, initialize your counter variable from `zero` and increment it after each iteration.

```
<?php 
    $counter = 0; 
    foreach($results as $row) {
         //your code
         if($counter == 1)
         {
              break;
         }
         $counter++;   
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Welcome @jord49 :)

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate up to the size of the array or 2 - the smaller of the two.

```
<?php 
$maxInd = min(2, count($results);
for ($i = 0; $i < $maxInd; ++$i) {
     $row =  $results[$i];
     // Do something interesting with $row
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

for ($i = 0, $count = count($results); $i < $count; ++$i) {
   var_dump($results[$i]);
   // or assign it to $result variable
   $result = $results[$i];
}

?>
```

But this will work only for collection there are some examples for example generators where you must use foreach.